# PHP sscanf pattern matching not working as expected

Tags: php, file-io, scanf

So I have abunch of files with formatted information, so several files containing multiple lines in this format:
id|visits|info|name

When I run the following code, $id and $visits get matched correctly, only $info and $name seem to have some kind of problem.
$info contains everything after the second | delimiter.
And $name is empty.

Am I missing something?

```
<?php
$dir = new DirectoryIterator('./logs/');
foreach ($dir as $file) {
   if (!$file->isDot()) {
       $filename = $file->getFilename();
       $currentfile = fopen("./logs/$filename","r");
       if ($currentfile) {
           while (($line = fgets($currentfile)) !== false) {
               $n = sscanf($line, "%d|%d|%s|%s", $id,$visits,$info,$name);
               print "$name was visited $visits times<br>";
           }
           fclose($currentfile);
       } else {
          print "Error: Couldn't open file.<br>";
       }
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: Might `info` or `name` substrings have spaces in them?  We don't have a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$dir = new DirectoryIterator('./logs/');
foreach ($dir as $file) {
    if (!$file->isDot()) {
        $filename = $file->getFilename();
        $currentfile = fopen("./logs/{$filename}", "r");
        if ($currentfile) {
            while (($line = fgets($currentfile)) !== false) {
                $n = sscanf($line, "%d|%d|%[^|]|%s", $id, $visits, $info, $name);
                print "{$name} was visited {$visits} times<br>";
            }
            fclose($currentfile);
        } else {
            print "Error: Couldn't open file.<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

You need to replace `%d|%d|%s|%s` with `%d|%d|%[^|]|%s` which can also contain regular expression. `%[^|]` reads all the characters except `|`. Since you're looking for a string in third delimiter, it takes all of the characters comes in the way till the end leaving the following delimiters to have empty literal value. Because you're using `|` as a delimiter, therefore, you need to prevent `|` from reading into `%s` to continue onto following delimiters. Numbers can be read easily but not easy for string when you have certain delimiters because string is everything from Numbers to any characters including delimiters except `space` since that's a reserved delimiter.

Here, you need to use regex to set certain conditions to match what you want and extract it to the variables.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Ah, right, thanks! Would this still be an issue if I were to use whitespaces as delimiters?

Comment: This code is not fail safe. It can fail sometimes depending upon your luck. For reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php#56076

Comment: Nope. There won't be issue for `space` character. Since `space` is already a default delimiter assigned to extract information, you don't need to worry about that. You need to care about it only when you're passing your own delimiter apart from `space` character. Hope you got it!

Answer (score 0):

There are few delimiters which creates this problem such as: **'.'** or **'|'**

You have to use some other delimiter to make it right.
For reference : http://php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php#81842

Comment: Why does it work with the first two variables though?

Comment: Because they are number and can be differentiated from string. But your third parameter `$info` is itself a string and that's why confusion with `|` happens.